# Java Spring REST API on GCP standard java11 app engine: Successful appengine:deploy but endpoint/route hangs indefinitely

Tags: java, spring, rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

After a successful deploy I am not able to view or hit my rest endpoints at all. I have looked up the documentation and my understanding is that the application would be running at:

`https://<project_id>.appspot.com`

or

`https://<version>-dot-<service>-dot-<project_id>.appspot.com.`

I am on the google-cloud-platform trial, trying to see if I can get an app to run before committing.

Both of these hostnames with any route following that I try simply hang. Even POST requests through postman hang.

What is happening?

This is the app.yaml

```
runtime: java11
env: standard

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored

manual_scaling:
  instances: 2
```

[successful_deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4LF8.png)

Logs show no activity after the spring project starting up.

gcloud app browse (with and without --version or --service parameters) just hangs "Loading..." indefinitely. With chrome inspection, the request is in status: "pending" forever.

EDIT:I now see that the app seems to be constantly restarting and logs show /_ah/start 500 errors. Seems GAE is listening for some type of response. How are these requests handled?

EDIT 2: I switched from the standard app engine to flex and using auto scaling in the yaml and the 500 error is gone. In the app logs, there are no critical, error, warning logs. But requests still hang.

Comment: Could you please try to follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard)? In order to rule out the possibility that is an issue related with App Engine.

Comment: @Andie, I followed a few spring boot petclinic tutorials completely with appengine, cloud sql. I also tried altering a petclinic project to include my custom routes in the controller and new models but I begin to get the issue. It just seems a lot like a networking issue because the logs don't show the requests that I send to it and I don't know how to diagnose it further.

Comment: The application was deployed correctly, right? I noticed that you mentioned that you changed to App engine Flex and the error is gone. Do you need more assistance? Or you are OK in App Engine flexible ?

Comment: Any idea how it got resolved? Stuck in the exactly same sort of issue

Answer (score 0):

_ah/start showing 500 indicates your spring app is probably having startup errors. Have you tried to start it locally with `mvn spring-boot:run` and did your app start fine? One common mistake is to deploy without removing tomcat/jetty dependencies from the pom file.

Comment: Yes, it runs well locally, calling a post to save to a cloud sql instance successfully. I switched from the standard app engine to flex and using auto scaling in the yaml and the error is gone. In the app logs, there are no critical, error, warning logs. But requests still hang.

Comment: You may have done this already. In case you haven't, check and confirm that you have given the right IAM permissions for IAM user service-[YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER]@gae-api-prod.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com. You need to give **Cloud SQL Client(preferred)** OR **Cloud SQL Editor** OR **Cloud SQL Admin** role for this service account. Also confirm that you are following the documentation available here - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine#setting_up

Comment: Can you remove the scaling configuration from your app.yaml and redeploy.